# Codeigniter update_batch return false if no data is changed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have found something disturbing in codeigniter, why is when I use `update_batch` and the data to be updated is the exact same as the data in the db, it always return false.

I can't seem to find any logical and good explanation and illustration in the CI documentation. I need it to return true even if there is no data changed, as it affect a great chunk of my codes, and only return false if failed to update db (i.e inserting a data that already exist into a unique column), then it should return false.

One more thing, how do I show db query error message in CI ? have read that it should be `$this->db->_error_message()`, but it keeps returning `Call to undefined method`. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions contain conflicting information:

- `update_batch()` has *never* returned boolean `false` if it has successfully executed at least one `UPDATE` query, regardless of whether any records were updated or not.

  - In CI2, it had a `void` return value in that case (implicitly converted to `null` if you want to use it).
  - In CI3, it returns an integer containing the number of rows affected (`int(0)` is not the same thing as `bool(false)`)
  - In both version trees, boolean `false` is only returned when you pass incorrect parameters.
- `_error_message()` used to exist on CI2, but its underscore prefix denotes that it was an internal method and you shouldn't be using it. CI3 has an `error()` method replacing it, which returns the code and message in an array, if there was an error in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's a very neat explanation. Why does not CI include this information in the doc. Well what I did was if(update_batch()) {return true} else {return false}, and thought it return false when nothing is affected. It is much clearer now and I can use the affected rows in my codes. Thanks man.

Comment: It does ... I don't know what kind of documentation you're looking at. This is the official one: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::update_batch